# How to get the friend list using Google+ API OAuth 2.0

Tags: php, google-plus

I am having signin with Google+ to retrieve the users basic profile info(Name, Urls, Location, Profile Picture). But I want to also retrieve the user-id of the users friend so that i can give him/her better suggestion of whom the user already know in my website.

```
$app_access_token = GetCH();
function GetCH(){
$ch = curl_init();
$pieces = explode(",", $_SESSION['access_token']); $piece = explode(":", $pieces[0]);
$token = str_replace('"',"",$piece[1]);
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=".$token;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETU`enter code here`RNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
if(substr($url,0,8)=='https://'){
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH,CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
}
$sendCH = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $sendCH;
};

if ($client->getAccessToken()){ 
  $me = $plus->people->get('me');
  $user_id = filter_var($me['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
  $url = filter_var($me['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
  $img = filter_var($me['image']['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
  $name = filter_var($me['displayName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

  // The access token may have been updated lazily.
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
```

}

For More Information: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/
But I am unable to figure how to get the friend list as an array from their API

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

You need to use: `$plus->people->listPeople`, you can find an example of usage in the [PHP quick start](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-php/blob/master/signin.php#L123) app.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should make sure you're using the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` OAuth2 scope to make sure they permit you to access some or all of their friends lists. You want to use the `people.list` API access point as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/#retrieve_a_collection_of_people) and detailed further on [this page](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list). Although they don't give a PHP code sample, I think you'll be able to use the $plus->people->list to make the call and get the information you want.

Comment: I have added OAuth2 Scope as https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login .But the Problem $plus->people->list('me'); is that PHP interprets ->list() as PHP inbuilt list function and generates Server Error, http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php .While seeking for permission it shows "This App would like to Know your name, basic info, and list of people you're connected to on Google+". But unable to make the call to retrieve the information due to PHP list() function.