# Retrieve user name from Google API

Tags: php, google-api

I am trying to modify Google's PHP [idtoken example](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/idtoken.php) to not only return email address (which is does) but also return first and last name.

I have modified line 36 from:

```
$client->setScopes('email');
```

to:

```
$client->setScopes( array( "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile" ) );
```

When examining `$token_data` is does not contain this information.  There was a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007560/get-userinfo-from-google-oauth-2-0-php-api) previously asked about this, but is uses `contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php` which is no longer included in the official `google-api-php-client` so I'd rather not use this approach.

What do I need to change in order for the code to return email address, first name, and last name?  Full name would be OK is first/last is not available.

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=".$token .After getting the access token, use this $me = $plus->people->get('me'); & $me['displayName'] is your name. [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880883/how-to-get-the-friend-list-using-google-api-oauth-2-0)

Comment: @Mahasish: How is `$plus` defined? I did not see it defined in the Question link that you gave. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get this working with the help of [Mahasish Shome](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1581133/mahasish-shome)'s comment.  I also had to enable "Google+ API" in the Google Developer Console.

Here is the code I needed to add:

```
require_once 'Google/Service/Plus.php';

// further on down in the example code...
$token_data = $client->verifyIdToken()->getAttributes(); // in preexisting code
// my new code...
$plus = new Google_Service_Plus( $client );
$me = $plus->people->get('me');

// further on down in the example code...
var_dump($token_data); // in preexisting code
// my new code...
var_dump($me);
```